# Gibt es eine deutsche Version von Hangul (der koreanischen Weise zu schreiben)?

Tags: written-language

Ich finde, Hangul ist fast die perfekte Weise zu schreiben. Jede Silbe ist ein (zusammengesetztes) Zeichen. Jedes Einzelzeichen entspricht genau einem Laut. Die Symbole versuchen, die Mundform nachzuahmen, sind aber trotzdem klar und eindeutig. Jeder kann Hangul in 15 Minuten lernen, ohne daß man Einschränkungen hinnehmen muß.

Daher frage ich mal die Sprachexperten: Gibt es hier bereits Versuche, sowas für Deutsch umzusetzen? Oder Äquivalente?
Ich konnte nichts finden.

Falls es sowas noch nicht gibt, ist jede Antwort die uns in diese Richtung weiterbringt willkommen.
Eine Liste aller Vokale im Standarddeutschen und lokalen Dialekten und Sprachverwandten gibt es ja auf Wikipedia. Man müsste nur die zur Schrift hinzufügen, die es im Koreanischen nicht gibt. Ausspracheprogramme und Grammatikkorrekturen z.B. könnten die Umwandlung von Wörtern in diese Schrift automatisieren. Was sonst noch fehlt… genau dafür bräuchte ich euch Experten.
Mein langfristiges Ziel wäre es dann, daraus ein Tastaturlayout (mit Tastenaufklebern für physische Tastaturen), eine Schriftart und einen Schnellkurs zu entwickeln, die alle quelloffen und gemeinfrei sein würden, und es zusammen jedem ermöglichten, dort innerhalb von nur einem Tag einzusteigen.

[Ich bin Programmierer, aber kein Sprachexperte, und bitte daher um schonende Behandlung. ;]

**EDIT:** Ich möchte nochmal spezifizieren, daß ich irrtümlich davon ausging, daß Hangul die aktuellen Laute perfekt abbildet, und tatsächlich der Mundform entspricht. Da ich jetzt erfuhr daß das nicht der Fall zu sein scheint, korrigiere ich darauf, daß ich dieses „ideale Hangul“ meinte. … Zudem sollen technische Einschränkungen aktueller Software oder Schriften kein Hindernis sein, da ich die zumindest bei quelloffenen Werken selber für mich abändern könnte. :)

Comment: Ich fürchte, die Frage (bzw. alles ab "Falls es sowas noch nicht gibt") ist etwas breit für das Frage-und-Antwort - Format hier. Das lässt sich kaum mit einer einzelnen "besten" Antwort beantworten.

Comment: Inhaltlich wäre ggf. anzumerken, dass beispielsweise [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koreanisches_Alphabet#Silbenbl%C3%B6cke) erklärt: "In jeder geschriebenen Silbe gibt es drei Positionen: Anlaut, Nukleus und Auslaut." Ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie "phonetisch komplex" im Koreanischen die Silben sind, aber es ist zu beachten, dass im Deutschen nicht nur "Fee" oder "As" eine Silbe sind, sondern "Strumpf", "Markt" und "Pflanz". Das führt dann entweder zu kleinteiligeren Silbenzeichen oder zu deutlich mehr Einzellautzeichen, um alles silbenweise abbilden zu können.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Stimmt. Die Lösung dafür wäre aber recht einfach. Jedes zusammengesetze Zeichen hat einen Vokal, der eine horizontale oder vertikale Linie ist. Weitere Konsonanten ließen sich hinzufügen, indem man die einfach verlängert, und dabei bestimmte Regeln einhält die die Lesungsreihenfolge festlegen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Zur ”besten” Antwort: Korrekt. Ich hatte nicht spezifiziert was hier als “besser” definiert wäre. Ich hatte halt etwas Inspiration erhofft die über meine hinausgeht. Schade daß diese Seite immer eine “beste” Antwort erwartet. Bisher finde ich alle Antworten toll, da sehr nützlich. Von daher: Einfach den Abschnitt ignorieren falls nicht brauchbar. :)

Answer (score 5):

Eine Schrift, welche die Laute des Deutschen genau abbildet, ist das [internationale phonetische Alphabet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Phonetisches_Alphabet). In der Praxis bestehen verschiedene Quasi-Rechtschreibungen, die weitgehend übereinstimmen, sich aber in einigen Details unterscheiden, wobei es meistens darum geht, ob über die [Laute](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonem) hinaus auch noch stellungsbedingte [Aussprachevarianten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophon) bestimmter Laute abgebildet werden sollen, die in vielen Gegenden auftreten, z.B. die verschiedenen Aussprachevarianten der Laute /r/ und /x/.

Ansonsten hat das Deutsche halt schon ein Alphabet, das die Aussprache abbildet, nämlich die [lateinische Schrift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateinisches_Alphabet). Jedes Alphabet ist eine Lautschrift – das ist es, was Alphabete von anderen Schrifttypen unterscheidet. Die Laut-Buchstaben-Beziehungen bestimmter Orthografien können mehr oder weniger eindeutig sein. Das ist aber bei den Hangul nicht anders als bei der lateinischen Schrift. Wäre das Deutsche schon seit anderthalb Jahrtausenden mit den Hangul geschrieben worden, so müssten wir ähnliche Abweichungen vom Lautprinzip erwarten, wie sie in der heutigen deutschen Orthografie zu beobachten sind.

Die oft gepriesene Eigenschaft der Hangul, nicht nur die Sprachlaute abbilden, sondern auch die Merkmale, aus denen diese Laute sich zusammensetzen, ist aus zwei Gründen zu relativieren: Erstens ist es umstritten, ob die Grundbuchstaben der Hangul wirklich die Mundform nachahmen und nicht – gemäss der bekannten Theorie von Gari Ledyard – aus der [Phagspa-Schrift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phagpa-Schrift) entlehnt sind. Zweitens bildet auch die lateinische Schrift durchaus bestimmte Lautmerkmale ab, vgl. Beatrice Primus (2004): “[A featural analysis of the Modern Roman Alphabet](https://doi.org/10.1075/wll.7.2.06pri)”, in: *Written Language & Literacy* 7(2), S. 235 – 274.

Schliesslich kann man problemlos Deutsch in Hangul schreiben – obwohl das Deutsche bereits ein eigenes Alphabet hat. Früher habe ich das selber gelegentlich als Spielerei getan, aber es ist schon eine Weile her.

### Edit: Mögliche Verwendung von Hangul für Deutsch

Hier als Spielerei eine mögliche Verwendung von Hangul für Deutsch. Die theoretische Freiheit in der Aneinanderreihung der Zeichen wäre eigentlich sehr gross, denn es können in jeder Silbe bis zu drei Konsonanten vor (Choseong) und drei Konsonanten nach (Jongseong) dem Vokal (Jungseong) auftreten – womit sich eigentlich die meisten deutschen Silben abbilden liessen. In der Praxis ist diese Freiheit jedoch doppelt eingeschränkt:

1. Die üblichen koreanischen Eingabemethoden können nur die vordefinierten Silbenzeichen produzieren. Vordefinierte Silbenzeichen existieren für diejenigen Lautkombinationen, die im modernen Koreanischen üblich sind. Sie erlauben einen einzigen Konsonant vor und höchstens zwei Konsonanten nach dem Vokal, wobei allerdings von den denkbaren 19 mal 19 Zweierkombinationen nur 11 existieren.
2. Fürs Altkoreanische sind darüber hinaus weitere Zeichen in Unicode kodiert. Einerseits handelt es sich um zusätzliche Konsonanten und Vokale, andererseits um zusätzliche Kombinationen von bis zu drei Konsonanten vor oder nach dem Vokal. Die Schriften, welche diese Zeichen darstellen können, scheinen dabei keine arbiträren Kombinationen von Konsonanten darzustellen, sondern nur die vordefinierten.

Die Programmierung (und Gestaltung) einer Schrift wäre vorstellbar, die alle Kombinationen von bis zu drei Konsonanten darstellte (oder man schreibt einfach von Hand – dann ist es natürlich trivial). Wenn ich es richtig sehe, so spricht von Unicode her eigentlich nichts gegen beliebige Dreier-Kombinationen. Die existierenden Implementationen stellen aber ausschliesslich die in Unicode codierten Kombinationen dar.

Der folgende Vorschlag beschränkt sich auf vordefinierte Silbenzeichen, wie sie mit den üblichen koreanischen Eingabemethoden produziert werden können. Die deutschen Laute werden also nicht perfekt abgebildet, aber wohl mindestens so gut wie mit bekannten Stenografie-Systemen. Wenn man altkoreanische Zeichen verwenden würde, liessen sich die deutschen Laute wohl noch besser abbilden (z.B. mit ᄛ/ퟝ für R), aber nicht mehr ohne weiteres eingeben.

#### Konsonanten

| Labial | Dental | Postalveolar | Velar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ㅂ B | ㄷ D | ㅈ DSCH | ㄱ G |
| ㅃ P | ㄸ T | ㅉ TSCH | ㄲ K |
| ㅍ (P)F | ㅌ Z | ㅊ SCH | ㅋ CH |
| ㅁ M | ㄴ N | - | ㅇ -NG |
| - | ㅅ S | - | - |
| - | ㅆ SS | - | - |
| - | ㄹ L/R | - | ㅎ H |

Bemerkungen:

- R am Silbenanfang als RJ schreiben, um es von L zu unterscheiden, z.B. 럐 «rau» vs. 래 «lau» (RI als RWI schreiben).
- L am Silbenende als LH schreiben, um es von R zu unterscheiden, z.B.. 팛 «Fall», «fahl» oder «Pfahl» vs. 팔 «fahr».
- P T TSCH K SS am Silbendende oder am Silbenanfang nach SCH als B D DSCH G S schreiben.
- Isolierte Konsonanten mit ㅡ schreiben, insb. Silbenanlaut-Cluster wie SCH + M oder B + R und Silbenauslaut-Cluster wie N + D, L + T usw.

#### Vokale

| Einfacher Vokal | J + Vokal | W + Vokal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ㅏ A | ㅑ JA | ㅘ WA |
| ㅐ AU | ㅒ JAU | ㅙ WAU |
| ㅓ E | ㅕ JE | ㅝ WE |
| ㅔ EI | ㅖ JEI | ㅞ WEI |
| ㅗ O | ㅛ JO | ㅚ WO |
| ㅜ U | ㅠ JU | ㅟ WU |
| ㅣ I | ㅡ (Kein Vokal/silbischer Konsonant) | ㅢ WI |

- Ü, Ö, EU/ÄU als I, E, EI schreiben (wie im klassischen Deutsch).
- Ungespannte Vokale mit Verdoppelung des folgenden Konsonanten markieren, falls es sich um einen einzelnen, wiederum von einem Vokal gefolgtem Konsonant handelt, z.B. 랻더 «Ratte» vs. 랴떠 «Rate», 붓서 «Busse» vs. 부써 «Buße» oder 츠덣러 «stelle» vs. 츠더러 «stehle».

#### Beispieltext

하버 눈, 앜, 피로소피, 유릣떠례 운드 머디틴 운드 레들 앸 떠오로기 둘크앳 츠두딜뜨, 믿 그료씀 버민. 다 싵 잌 눈, 잌 알믈 똘 운드 빈 소 끄룩 앐 의 투폴, 헤써 마깃들, 헤써 독돌 갈 운드 티어 촌 안 디 터흔 얄 허럪 허럅 운드 꿜 운드 끄륨 메너 치를 안 덜 나서 허륨, 운드 멀꺼, 닷 읠 닋 읫슨 껀는, 닷 읧 밀 칠 닷 헕 플브런는.

Comment: Hangul ist mittlerweile auch schon fast 600 Jahre alt. Ich nehme an, dass auch Koreanisch sich in dieser Zeit verändert hat. Stimmt die moderne Schreibweise von Wörtern, die sich verändert haben, noch mit der historischen Schreibweise überein? Oder gibt es von Zeit zu Zeit koreanische Rechtschreibreformen, wenn Aussprache und Schreibweise nicht mehr zusammenpassen?

Comment: "Isolierte Konsonanten mit ㅡ schreiben, insb. Silbenanlaut-Cluster wie SCH + M oder B + R und Silbenauslaut-Cluster wie N + D, L + T usw." - das ist ein "Workaround", der eine valide Codierung mit den verfügbaren Zeichen ergibt. Mir scheint es allerdings, als würde das genau dem in der Frage beschriebenen Ziel zuwiderlaufen, denn der OP nennt praktisch als ersten vorteilhaften Aspekt "Jede Silbe ist ein (zusammengesetztes) Zeichen." Und diese Eigenschaft verliert man ja dadurch, dass man Konsonantencluster über mehrere Zeichen aufteilt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Völlig richtig – aber zur Darstellung von derartigen Korsonantenkombinationen, für die er keine vordefinierten Unicode-Charaktere gibt, müsste man eben – wie ich erklärt habe – zuerst einmal eine neue Schriftart programmieren und gestalten. Ferner bräuchte es dann auch noch eine neue Eingabemethode, mit der sich die gewählten Zeichen auch eingeben lassen, aber das ist vergleichsweise ein eher triviales Problem.

Comment: @mach: Sicherlich, aber da der OP schrieb "Man müsste nur die [Vokale] zur Schrift hinzufügen, die es im Koreanischen nicht gibt." schien es mir, als solle dies nicht als Ausschlusskriterium gelten. Ich möchte nur darauf hinaus, dass man bei dieser Frage auf zwei sehr unterschiedliche Ziele hinarbeiten kann: Einerseits eine technisch eher einfach machbare Lösung, die eine eindeutige Abbildung deutscher Worte auf den bestehenden koreanischen Zeichensatz erlaubt, eine Art Umcodierung. Anderseits eine neu entwickelte Schrift, welche die konzeptuellen Vorzüge und Ideen von Hangul aufgreift ...

Comment: ... und sie für die deutsche Sprache angepasst nutzbar macht. Soweit ich die Frage verstehe, scheint sie eher in letztere Richtung zu gehen, aber gegebenenfalls sollte dies in der Frage klargestellt werden.

Comment: Danke für diese extensive Antwort. Ich möchte anmerken, daß Deutsch in lateinisch inakzeptable Mehrfachzuordnungen hat, und das mein Grund für Hangul war. Wenn Hangul da auch Mängel hat, und die Mundform nicht abbildet, muß ich meine Frage dahingehend ändern, daß ich natürlich ein “eindeutiges mundformabbildendes Hangul” als Basis nehmen würde. :)

Comment: Zur Software die nur koreanische Kombinationen kann: Als Programmierer habe ich kein Problem damit, diese Software und Schriftarten anzupassen. Und sollte es tatsächlich bei anderen Leuten beliebt werden, würde ich diese für quelloffenen Betriebssysteme sowieso anbieten. :)
Bei den Schriftarten hatte ich eh nicht vor, koreanische zu benutzen, weil die Laute im Koreanischen ja eh nicht zu 100% gleich klingen wie die deutschen.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: Ich denke nicht, dass es ein «eindeutiges mundformabbildendes Hangul» gibt. Vielmehr existieren verschiedene Theorien über den Ursprung der Hangul-Basiszeichen. Ich sehe nicht, warum es ein Hindernis für die Verwendung koreanischer Schriftarten sein sollte, wenn die Laute nicht zu 100 % gleich klingen. Schriftarten sind ja immer eine Abstraktion von den Lauten, auch im Fall der Hangul. Die Programmierung neuer Schriftarten ist allerdings eine trickreiche Aufgabe, weil auch viel Gestaltungsarbeit dazugehört.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: Ich habe ausserdem gefragt, ob vielleicht schon solche Schriftarten existieren: [Is there a Korean font that can display arbitrary jamo combinations?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/is-there-a-korean-font-that-can-display-arbitrary-jamo-combinations). Es sieht nicht danach aus (und ausserdem dürfte wohl immer gleich die Sinnfrage gestellt werden). Vom Standard  her spricht aber glaub ich nichts dagegen, vgl. [Unicode Text Segmentation § Hangul Syllable Boundary Determination](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Hangul_Syllable_Boundary_Determination).

Answer (score 1):

Die nächste Entsprechung zu Hangul wäre wohl *[Stenografie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenografie)* - Schnellschrift basierend auf Lauten und Silben, weiterhin Kürzeln für besonders häufig vorkommende Wörter. Sie wurde verwendet, um schnelle Mitschriften von Diktaten anfertigen zu können. Stenografie ist heute größtenteils durch den Einsatz von Diktiergeräten obsolet geworden, ist allerdings z.B. in Abgeordnetenhäusern zur Aufzeichnung von Plenarsitzungen immer noch gebräuchlich.

Stenografie ist allerdings keine spezifisch deutsche Erfindung, sondern eigentlich eine britische - Sie wurde nur an die deutsche Sprache mit spezifischen Silben- und Worthäufigkeiten angepaßt.

Sehr gute Stenografen können bis zu 480 Silben/Minute mitschreiben - Das ist fast doppelt so schnell, wie typische Nachrichtensendungen verlesen werden.

Comment: Hangul unterteilt den Sprachfluss in Silben und innerhalb der Silben in Laute (Phone). Damit ist Hangul eine silbengruppierende Buchstabenschrift. Jeder Laut hat ein eigenes Zeichen, vergleichbar mit den Symbolen der internationalen Lautschrift. In der Stenographie entspricht aber **nicht** jedes Symbol genau einem Laut. In der Stenographie gibt es viele Symbole, die mehreren Lauten entsprechen. Beispielsweise wird das Wort *Strumpf* (7 Laute) mit nur 3 Steno-Symbolen geschrieben (str - u - mpf). Außerdem gibt es Symbole für ganze Wörter: Das Wort *besonders* (3 Silben mit ...

Comment: ... insgesamt 9 Lauten) wird mit nur einem einzigen Steno-Symbol geschrieben. Auch für *zusammen* (3 Silben, 7 Laute) reicht ein einziges Symbol. Damit ist Steno einem Schriftsystem wie Hangul sogar weniger nahe als die ganz normale lateinische Schrift.

Comment: Das mit den Zeichen für Kürzel u.ä. halte ich für eine Fehlentwicklung, die von *Ithkuil* schön auf die Spitze getrieben wurde. :D … Kurz: Man braucht ganz schnell sehr viele Zeichen, und hat dann nur wieder das selbe Problem wie am Anfang, nur auf einer anderen Ebene. …
Der Fehler hier ist der selbe, der auch bei der Softwareentwicklung auftritt. Kurz: Beim iPhone gibt es eine App für alles… weil man eine separate App für jede Permutation von Funktionskombinationen *braucht!* … Im UNIX-Prinzip dagegen tut jedes Programm nur eines, und das richtig, und man kann sie zu allem *kombinieren*. :)

Comment: Zudem erzeugt diese nichtmodulare Kombinierung zu Kürzeln viele Probleme bei der Verarbeitung durch Software. Da es die Zeichen der Laute für die die Kürzel stehen ja auch einzeln gibt. Und genau solche Dinge möchte ich ja vermeiden.
… **Generell ist die Antwort aber trotzdem schön und hilfreich und interessant. Die Vorteile der Stenografie kann man ja auch ohne diese Nachteile trotzdem integrieren. :)**

Answer (score 1):

Hier eine Art und Weise, wie die koreanischen Buchstaben theoretisch perfekt fürs Deutsche adaptiert werden könnten (im Gegensatz zu meiner anderen Antwort).

Der folgende Vorschlag geht von den folgenden Voraussetzungen aus:

1. Nur Zeichen verwenden, die als Unicode-Charakter kodiert sind.
2. Bei den Kombinationen von Zeichen nicht darauf achten, ob sie in Unicode kodiert sind.

Das Koreanische erlaubt pro Silbeneinheit maximal 3 Silbenanlaut-Konsonanten, 3 Vokale, 3 Silbenauslaut-Konsonanten (nota bene: Zeichen wie ㅃ sind bereits eine Zweierkombination!). Damit lassen sich alle deutschen Silben darstellen, vorausgesetzt, man hat ein eigenes Zeichen für /st/ im Auslaut. Dies ist erforderlich für Silben wie «stampfst», die dann kodiert würden als Silbenanlaut ⟨ʃ⟩⟨t⟩, Vokal ⟨a⟩, Silbenauslaut ⟨m⟩⟨pf⟩⟨st⟩.

### Konsonanten

|  | Labial | Dental | Postalveolar | Velar | Glottal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lenis-Plosive | ㅂ b | ㄷ d | ㅈ dʒ | ㄱ ɡ | ㆆ ʔ |
| Fortis-Plosive | ㅃ p | ㄸ t | ㅉ tʃ | ㄲ k | - |
| Affrikaten | ㆄ pf | ㅌ ts | - | - | - |
| Lenis-Frikative | ㅍ f | ㅅ s | ㅊ ʃ | ㅋ x | ㅎ h |
| Fortis-Frikative | - | ㅆ ss | - | - | - |
| Stimmhafte Frikative | ㅍㅍ v* | - | ㅊㅊ ʒ | - | - |
| Nasale | ㅁ m | ㄴ n | - | ㅇ ∅-/-ŋ | - |
| Liquide | - | ㄹ l, ᄛ r | - | - | - |
| Kombinationen | - | ᇫ -st | - | - | - |

Bemerkungen:

- ㅍㅍ für v wird nur im Anlaut /vr/ wie in «Wrack» benötigt.
- In Sequenzen von Obstruenten die einfachen Zeichen verwenden, nicht die verdoppelten, also beispielsweise /ʃt/ als ㅊㄷ schreiben, nicht als ㅊㄸ.

### Vokale

| Einfacher Vokal | j + Vokal | ʋ + Vokal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ㅣ i | ퟄ ji | ㅢ ʋi |
| ㅓ e | ㅕ je | ㅝ ʋe |
| ㅓㅏ æ | ㅕㅏ jæ | ㅝㅏ ʋæ |
| ㅡ y | ᆜ jy | ᆖ ʋy |
| ᆞ ə/ø | ᆝ jø | ㅗᆞ ʋø |
| ㅜ u | ㅠ ju | ᆍ ʋu |
| ㅗ o | ㅛ jo | ᆂ ʋo |
| ㅏ a | ㅑ ja | ㅘ ʋa |

Dipthonge:

| Einfacher Diphthong | j + Diphthong | ʋ + Diphthong |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ㅐ aɪ | ㅒ jaɪ | ㅙ ʋaɪ |
| ㅚ ɔʏ | ᆈ jɔʏ | ᆂㅣ ʋɔʏ |
| ᅷ aʊ | ᆤ jaʊ | ㅘㅜ ʋaʊ |

Betonung:

- Kurze, betonte Silbe: 〮
- Lange, betonte Silbe: 〯

Bemerkungen:

- Lange und kurze Vokale werden durch das Betonungszeichen voneinander unterschieden, ebenso /œ/ (markiert mit 〮 als kurz und betont) von /ə/ (unbetont, also nicht markiert).

### Beispiele

Hier zwei Beispiele mit maximalem An- bzw. Auslaut, was in den existierenden Schriftarten nicht darstellbar ist:

- /ʃtampfst/ «stampfst»: ᄎ담ᇴᇫ〮
- /ʃtrikst/ «strickst»: ᄎᄃᄛᅵᆨᇫ〮
- /kʋæːlst/ «quälst»: 꿔ᅡᆯᇫ〯
- /ʃtrʊmpf/ «Strumpf»: ᄎᄃᄛᅮᆷᇴ〮
- /markt/ «Markt»: 마ퟝᆨᆮ〮
- /pflants/ «pflanz»: ᅗ란ᇀ〮

Und zur Abwechslung ein Beispiel, dass mit «intelligenten» Schriftarten bereits darstellbar ist:

- /ɡəˈjaʊlə/ «Gejaule»: ᄀᆞᄋᆤ〯ᄅᆞ

### Hinweis zur Kodierung

Zu beachten ist übrigens, dass die Hangul-Konsonanten typischerweise als drei verschiedene Charaktere kodiert sind:

1. Silbenanlaut-Variante (Choseong), z.B. ᄇ U+1107 HANGUL CHOSEONG PIEUP
2. Silbenauslaut-Variante (Jongseong), z.B. ᆸ U+11B8 HANGUL JONGSEONG PIEUP
3. Isolierte Variante, z.B. ㅂ U+3142 HANGUL LETTER PIEUP

Ebenso existieren die Vokale typischerweise als zwei Charaktere:

1. Silbeninlaut-Variante (Jungseong), z.B. ᅵ U+1176 HANGUL JUNGSEONG I
2. Isolierte Variante, z.B. ㅣ U+3163 HANGUL LETTER I

Bei der freien Zusammensetzung von Zeichen zu Silben müssen die entsprechenden Choseong-, Jungseong- oder Jongseong-Varianten verwendet werden. Die isolierten Varianten können für eine Eingabemethode nützliche sein: Ich tippe das (isolierte) Zeichen, und je nach Umgebung entscheidet die Eingabemethode, ob daraus ein Choseong, ein Jongseong, ein Jungseong oder ein isoliertes Zeichen wird.

Comment: Ich bin *sehr* beeindruckt. Ich hätte keine Antworten von der Qualität erwartet! Ganz große Klasse!